# как правильно передать параметры

Tags: javascript

Не могу разобраться почему в console.log выходит только first. Подскажите, пожалуйста, верный синтаксис.

```
function concatStrings(strs) {
  let separator = '',
    result = '';
  for (let str of strs) {
    if (str[0] && typeof str[0] !== 'string') return result;
    if (str[0]) result += str[0];
    if (str[1]) separator = str[1];
    result += separator;
  }
  return result;
}

concat = (strs) => strs.join('');

console.log(concatStrings('first', 'second', 'third'));
```

Comment: Пробуй отладку и смотри что у тебя происходит на каждом шаге

Comment: Пока вообще не ясно зачем все эти if str[0] if str[1] и пр, если тебе банально надо в цикле пройтись и через разделитель сконкатенировать всё. а потом у результирующей строки в конце отрезать лишний разделитель

Comment: function concatStrings(...strs){}